# Android Thing Raspberry Pi installed apk starting issue

Tags: android, android-studio, raspberry-pi, android-things

I have a Raspberry Pi with Android Things. Android Things image installed in Raspberry Pi is build with latest configuration.
I have a project which is getting installed in Android Thing(Raspberry Pi) when it is directly build and run from Android Studio. When I only build apk and try to Install that apk using `adb install` it is getting installed successfully but while running it is getting stuck in First Activity screen.

I tried below command:

```
adb install test.apk
```

Above command is successfully installing apk but while running it is getting stuck on first Activity Screen.
Also tried below commands:

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.test/.MainActivity    // This is also running installed app but getting stuck.
```

Android Studio      :  4.0

SDK Version         :  29

OS                  :  Windows Home

Bit                 :  x64

Raspberry Pi 3B

Comment: Try `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.test/.MainActivity`.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko thank you for replying. I tried your given command but same issue occurred, while running apk is getting stuck.